# NHibernate tries to cast Entity to IDictionary when saving

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a very simple setup:

```
public class Role
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        Permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
    }
}

public enum Permission
{
    ACCESS_USER_MANAGER, [... and many more]
}
```

And according mapping files:

```
<class entity-name="UserManager.Model.Role" table="roles">
    <id name="Id" type="int">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="name" type="string"/>

    <set name="Permissions" table="permissions">
        <key column="role"/>
        <element column="name" type="string"/>
    </set>

</class>
```

But, when I try to create a role and save it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestRoles()
{
    ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
    Role role = new Role();
    role.Name = "Test-Role";
    role.Permissions.Add(Permission.ACCESS_USER_MANAGER);
    _session.Save(role);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

I get an exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'UserManager.Model.Role' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionary'.

Why does NHibernate try to cast my Entity to an IDictionary? And, more importantly: How can I make this work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see three problems here. Firstly you've used the mapping related to:

#### [4.4. Dynamic models](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels)

A cite:

> The following examples demonstrates the representation using Maps (Dictionary). First, in the mapping file, an entity-name has to be declared instead of (or in addition to) a class name:
>
> `<hibernate-mapping>`
>        `<class entity-name="Customer">`
>  `...`

And this is what we can see in the mapping above **`entity-name`** instead of **`name`**. As the example shows if we use dynamic then we would continue:

```
// Create a customer
var frank = new Dictionary<string, object>();
frank["name"] = "Frank";
...
// Save customer
s.Save("Customer", frank);
```

See:

#### [5.1.3. class](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class)

A cite:

```
<class
    name="ClassName"                              (1)
    ...
```

> (1)   name: The fully qualified .NET class name of the persistent class (or interface), including its assembly name.

So, we cannot use dynamic mapping but the standard class mapping:

```
// Instead of this
// <class entity-name="UserManager.Model.Role" table="roles">

// we should use this
<class name="UserManager.Model.Role" table="roles">
```

Secondly, the Enum should be mapped to **`int`** column with this element mapping *(also I used `permissionId` as column name to show that it should be int)*:

```
<element column="permissionId" type="UserManager.Model.Permission"/>
```

Summary this should be working mapping:

```
<class name="UserManager.Model.Role" table="roles">
    <id name="Id" type="int">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="name" type="string"/>

    <set name="Permissions" table="permissions">
        <key column="role"/>
        //<!--<element column="name" type="string"/>-->
        <element column="permissionId" type="UserManager.Model.Permission"/>
    </set>

</class>
```

The third issue, could be swapping of `iesi` and `System` **`ISet`**. It should be like this:

```
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;
public class Role
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
      //Permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
        Permissions = new HashedSet<Permission>();
    }
}
```