# NHibernate - DuplicateMappingException duplicate import: view refers to both

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am getting this exception:

> duplicate import: View refers to both
>   TrackingPrototype.Models.vTSPrecedenceExclude, TrackingPrototype,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null and
>   TrackingPrototype.Models.vDMPrecedenceExclude, TrackingPrototype,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (try using
>   auto-import="false")

I have 2 views, vDMPrecedenceExclude and vTSPrecedenceExclude.

2 mapping files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="TrackingPrototype"
                   namespace="TrackingPrototype.Models">

  <class name="vDMPrecedenceExclude" table="vDMPrecedenceExclude" entity-name="View">
    <id name="id" type="Int32" column="id" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="EngagementID" />
    <property name="Issued" />
    <property name="ReturnedByPresenter" />
    <property name="SentToProducer" />
    <property name="ReturnedByProducer" />
    <property name="Executed" />
    <property name="ExcludedBitSet" />
    <property name="Change" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="TrackingPrototype"
                   namespace="TrackingPrototype.Models">

  <class name="vTSPrecedenceExclude" table="vTSPrecedenceExclude" entity-name="View">
    <id name="id" type="Int32" column="id" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="EngagementID" />
    <property name="Received" />
    <property name="Drafted" />
    <property name="SentToProducer" />
    <property name="SentToPresenter" />
    <property name="ExcludedBitSet" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Which are loaded like this:

```
configuration.AddFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Mappings\vDMPrecedenceExclude.hbm.xml"));
configuration.AddFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Mappings\vTSPrecedenceExclude.hbm.xml"));
```

The exception is referring to the second line.

and models defined as:

```
namespace TrackingPrototype.Models
{
    public class DealMemoTracking : Tracking
    {
        public virtual DateTime? Issued { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? ReturnedByPresenter { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? SentToProducer { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? ReturnedByProducer  { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? Executed { get; set; }
        public virtual int ExcludedBitSet { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace TrackingPrototype.Models
{
    public class TicketScalesTracking : Tracking
    {
        public virtual DateTime? Received { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? Drafted { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? SentToProducer { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? SentToPresenter { get; set; }
        public virtual int ExcludedBitSet { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace TrackingPrototype.Models
{
    public class vDMPrecedenceExclude : DealMemoTracking
    {
    }
}

namespace TrackingPrototype.Models
{
    public class vTSPrecedenceExclude : TicketScalesTracking
    {
    }
}
```

I am not fully understanding this error, any ideas why I am getting this exception?

Thank you.

Comment: what is `entity-name` referring to?  I don't think it can be the same (but may be wrong). Can you try removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in documentation

[4.4. Dynamic models](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels)

> Persistent entities don't necessarily have to be represented as POCO classes at runtime. NHibernate also supports dynamic models (using Dictionaries of Dictionarys at runtime) . With this approach, you don't write persistent classes, only mapping files.
>
> By default, NHibernate works in normal POCO mode. You may set a default entity representation mode for a particular ISessionFactory using the default_entity_mode configuration option
>
> The following examples demonstrates the representation using Maps (Dictionary). First, in the mapping file, an **entity-name** has to be declared instead of (or in addition to) a class name:

```
<class entity-name="Customer">
```

So, that's it, if we do have a POCO class we should use the `name` attribute. Not the `entity-name`. The change which should make it:

```
// instead of this
// <class name="vDMPrecedenceExclude" table="vDMPrecedenceExclude" entity-name="View">
// use this
<class name="vDMPrecedenceExclude" table="vDMPrecedenceExclude">
```

Please check also this:

- [NHibernate tries to cast Entity to IDictionary when saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206528/nhibernate-tries-to-cast-entity-to-idictionary-when-saving)